# How to delete specific Excel columns?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

A macro I have written works but it won't delete all of the specified columns. What could be the problem? I want to delete all of these specified columns from all tabs/sheets.

```
Sub Dosomething()
  Dim xSh As Worksheet
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For Each xSh In Worksheets
      xSh.Select
      Call DeleteColumns
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub DeleteColumns()
  Dim ColumnsToDelete As String, V As Variant
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "AAFA Certified|AATCC 116 Grade|AATCC 16.1-2014 Grade|AATCC 16.3-2014 Grade|AATCC 8 Grade|AC Rated|AC Rating|ACT Flammability Guidelines Compliant|ADA Compliant"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "Additional Intended Use For Child|AHAM CADR Dust rating|AHAM CADR Pollen rating|AHAM CADR Smoke rating|AHAM Certified|AHMA Compliant|AHRI Certified|American Cornhole Association (ACA) Certified|ANSI A117.1 Compliant|ANSI A137.1 Compliant"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "ANSI IT9.2 Compliant|ANSI Z1.5A/CGA 9.1M Certified|ANSI Z124.1.2 Compliant|ANSI Z124.3 Compliant|ANSI Z124.6-97 Compliant|ANSI Z358 Compliant|ANSI/BHMA A156 Certified|ANSI/BIFMA e3 Furniture Sustainability Standard|ANSI/BIFMA X5.1 Office Seating|ANSI/BIFMA X5.11 Large Occupant Office Seating"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "ANSI/BIFMA X5.3 Vertical Files|ANSI/BIFMA X5.4 Lounge & Public Seating|ANSI/BIFMA X5.5 Desk Products|ANSI/BIFMA X5.6 Panel Systems|ANSI/BIFMA X5.9 Storage|ANSI/BIFMA X6.1 Educational Seating|ANSI/BIFMA X7.1 Standard for Formaldehyde & TVOC Emissions|ANSI/ESD S20.20 Certified|ANSI/NISO Z39.48 Compliant|ANSI/SOHO S6.5 Small Office/Home Office"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "APMA Certified| ASHRAE 62.2 Standard Compliant| ASME A112.18.1 Compliant| ASME A112.18.2 Compliant| ASME A112.19.1 Compliant| ASME A112.19.2 Compliant| ASME A112.19.3 Compliant| ASP:02:01 Certification| ASSE 1001 Certified| ASSE 1006 Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "ASSE 1016 Certified| ASTM E1590-07| ASTM F1004-19 Certified| ASTM F1148-17| ASTM F1148-18 Certified| ASTM F1169 - 13 Certified| ASTM F1821 - 16 Certified| ASTM F1912-17 Certified| ASTM F1917 - 12 Certified| ASTM F2057 - 14 Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "ASTM F2057 - 17 Certified| ASTM F2057 - 19 Certified| ASTM F2085 - 12 Certified| ASTM F2088-15| ASTM F2194 Certified| ASTM F2225-15| ASTM F2388 - 18 Certified| ASTM F2613 - 17 Certified| ASTM F2933-18 Certified| ASTM F3084 - 16 Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "ASTM F3096 - 14 Certified| ASTM F3317-18 Certified| ASTM F381-16| ASTM F406 - 10a Certified| ASTM F406 - 15 Certified| ASTM F406 - 17 Certified| ASTM F963 - 17 Certified| ASTM F963-11| ATA Rated| AZO Free"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "BHFTI Upholstered Furniture Flammability Compliant| BIFMA G1 Ergonomics Guideline for Furniture| BIFMA HCF 8.1 - Healthcare Furniture Design| Blauer Engel| BPA Free| BS 5287: 1988 Certified| BS 5852 Certified| BS 5867-2:2008 Certified| BS 7176: 2007 Certified| BS 7177:2008+A1:2011 Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "BS EN 13120: 2009 + A1: 2014 (Requirements for Window Blinds or Drapery Cords) - EU ONLY| BS EN 71 Compliant - EU ONLY| BS EN 716-1 Compliant - EU ONLY| BS EN12790 Certified| Bulb Included| Bulb Type| CAL TB 116 Compliant| CAL TB 117-2013 Compliant| CALGreen Compliant| California AB 1953 Compliant"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "California Pesticide (DPR) Registration Number| California Proposition 65 Warning Required| Canada Product Restriction| CARB Phase II Compliant (formaldehyde emissions)| CE Certified| CEE Rating| Certifications| CertiPUR-US Certified| cETL Certified| cETL Listed"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "CFC Free| Chemicals of Concern Compliant| Children’s Product Certificate (CPC)| CISPR 22 Compliant| Commercial ONLY Certifications| Commercial OR Residential Certifications| Commercial Warranty| Composite Wood Product (CWP)| Consumer Safety Specification for Bunk Beds ASTM F1427 - 13| Contains Flame Retardant Materials"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "Country of Origin| Country of Origin - Additional Details| CPAI-84 Compliant| CPG Compliant| CPSC - 15 U.S. Code § 1278a - Children’s Products Containing Lead| CPSC - 16 CFR 1213 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1217 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1218 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1219 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1220 Compliant"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "CPSC - 16 CFR 1234 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1237 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1238 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1239 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1303 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1500.49 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1513 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1630 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1631 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR 1632 Compliant"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "CPSC - 16 CFR 1633 Compliant| CPSC - 16 CFR Part 1130-Requirements For Consumer Registration Of Durable Infant Or Toddler Products| CPSC - 16 CFR Part 1307-Prohibition Of Children's Toys And Child Care Articles Containing Specified Phthalates| CPSIA Compliant| CPSIA or CPSC Compliant| Cradle to Cradle Certified| CRI Certified| CRI Green Label Certified| CRI Green Label Plus Certified| CSA B125 Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "CSA B125.1 Certified| CSA B125.2 Certified| CSA B13 Certified| CSA B45 Certified| CSA B45.1 Certified| CSA B45.2 Certified| CSA Certified| CSA Listed for Canada| CSA Listed for USA| cUL Listed"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "cUPC Certified| Dark Sky Compliant| DECT 6.0 Compliant| DIN EN 12935 Certified| Dry, Damp, or Wet Location Listed - CAN| Dry, Damp, or Wet Location Listed - USA| EEP Compliant| EIA Compliant| EISA 2007 Compliant| EISA Compliant"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "Emergency Feed| EN 1130-1:1996 (Safety Requirements for Cribs and Cradles) - EU ONLY| EN 12221-1 (Standards for Changing Tables) - EU ONLY| EN 13219 (Standards for Trampolines) - EU ONLY| EN 14878: 2007 (Requirements for Children's Sleepwear) - EU ONLY| EN 14988-1 (Safety Standards for High Chairs) - EU ONLY| EN 15312 (Safety Standards for Multi-Sport Equipment) - EU ONLY| EN 1725 (Safety Standards for Adult Beds) - EU ONLY| EN 1930 (Standards for Child Gates and Safety Barriers) - EU ONLY| EN 50291-1 (Standards for Smoke Detectors and CO Detectors) - EU ONLY"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "EN 54-12 (Standards for Smoke Detectors and CO Detectors) - EU ONLY| EN 71 Compliant| EN 71-14:2018 Compliant| EN 747-1 (Standards for Childrens Bunk Beds) - EU ONLY| EN 748 (Safety Standards for Football Goals) - EU ONLY| Energy Label Type| Energy Policy Act 1992 Compliant| Energy Star Compliant| EPA Compliant| EPA Pesticide Registration Number"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "EPAct 2005 Compliant| EPP Compliant| ETL Listed| EuroLatex ECO-Standard| FCC Compliant| FCC Part 15 Certified| FCC Part 15 Compliant| FCC Part 68 Compliant| FDA Approved| FIRA Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "Fire Rated| Fire Resistant| FISP Certified| FloorScore Certification| FM Approved| FourB Compliant| FSC Certified| General Certificate of Conformity (GCC)| Glass Doors and Enclosures Regulations SOR/2016-174| Glazed Ceramics and Glassware Regulations SOR/2016-175"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "GOLS 3.0 (Global Organic Latex Standard) Certified| GOLS License Expiry Date| GOLS License Number| Goodweave Certified| GOTS 5.0 (Global Organic Textile Standard) Certified| GOTS License Expiry Date| GOTS License Number| Grade of GOLS Certification| Grade of GOTS Certification| Green Compliance"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "GREENGUARD Certified| GREENGUARD Gold Certified| GS (Geprüfte Sicherheit) verzeichnet| GSA Approved| Health Canada - SOR/2016-176 Compliant| Health Canada - SOR/2016-179 Compliant| Health Canada - SOR/2016-183 Compliant| Health Canada Compliant| HFES 100 Certified Ergonomic| HVI 2100 Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "HVI Certified| IAPMO Certified| IATA Compliant| Indoor Air Quality Certified| IP Rating| IPEMA Certified| ISO 14000 Certified| ISO 14001 Certified| ISO 9000 Certified| ISO 9001 Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "ITSF Compliant| ITTF Approved| ITTO Compliant| Janka Hardness Rating (PSI)| JPMA Certified| Kettles Regulations SOR/2016-181| Knife Included| Lacey Act Compliant| Latex Free| Lead Free"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "LEED Project Appropriate| LM-79 Certified| LM-80 Certified| Low Lead Compliant| Mattress Flammability Testing - Public Occupancy Use| Maximum Wattage (per bulb)| MERV Rating| MET Listed| Minnesota 325F.177 Compliant| MOHS - Surface Hardness"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "NAECA Certified| NAHB Compliant| NEMA Certified| NFPA 253 or ASTM E648 Certified| NFPA Compliant| NFSI Certified| NHPA Approved| NOMITE Certified| Non-Toxic| NRPA Certified"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "NSF Certified| NSF/ANSI 184 Certified| NSF/ANSI 3 Certified| NSF/ANSI 336 Compliant| NSF/ANSI 61 Certified| OEKO-TEX Standard 100 Certified| OSHA Compliant| PAT Tested| PEFC Certified| PEI Rated"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "PEI Rating| PFOA Free| Phthalate Free| Product Warranty| PTFE Free| PTFE or PFOA| PTFE or PFOA Free| Reason for Restriction| Responsible Down Standard Certified| RoHS Compliant"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "SATRA Approved| SCC Compliant| SCS Certified| SDWA Compliant| SFI Certified| SOR/2016-152 - Canadian Regulation - Cribs, Cradles and Bassinets| SOR/2016-193 - Surface Coating Materials Regulations| SOR/2018-83 -Consumer Products Containing Lead Regulations| Stiftung Warentest Note| TAA Compliant"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "TB 117-2013 Compliant| TB 133 Compliant| TCLP Compliant| Textile Flammability Regulations SOR/2016-194| Textile Labelling and Advertising Regulations (C.R.C., c. 1551)| Tipover Restraint Device Included| Title 20 - California Code of Regulations| Title 24 Compliant| Total Recycled Content (Percentage)| Total Wattage"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "Toys Regulations SOR/2016-195| TSA Compliant| TSCA Title VI Compliant (formaldehyde emissions)| TÜV Certified| TÜV Rheinland zertifiziert| UL 10B Compliant| UL 10C Compliant| UL 1678 Listed| UL 1951 Listed| UL 2108 Listed"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "UL 4041 - Safety Standard for Outdoor Furniture| UL Listed| ULC ORD-C627.1-2008 - Unvented Ethyl Alcohol Fuel Burning Decorative Appliances| ULC/ORD-C627.1-2008| Uniform Packaging and Labeling Regulations (UPLR) Compliant| UPC Certified| USATT Approved| USDA Compliant| USDA Organic/ NOP Certified| USDA/NOP Certificate Number"
  ColumnsToDelete = ColumnsToDelete & "|" & "USDA/NOP License Expiry Date| USPS Approved| Vermont Act 193 Compliant| VESA Compliant| Washington State VIAQ Code Compliant| Wattage| WEEE Recycling Required| WQA Gold Seal Certified| WW-P-541 Certified"
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each V In Split(ColumnsToDelete, "|")
    Rows(1).Find(Trim(V), , , xlWhole, , , False).EntireColumn.Delete
  Next
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't rely on `Select`; pass `DeleteColumns` a `Worksheet` variable.

Comment: String to string comparison is finiky, it could be as easy as typo or extra spaces in the data.  There is no way for us to know why.  You will need to go line by line and make sure a match is found for each

Comment: @BigBen what should i do then?

Comment: @ScottCraner I looked at the column names and they're exactly correct

Comment: By looking one cannot see extra spaces, or spaces before or after the words.  You will need to debug and go line by line to find where matches are not found.  we cannot do that for you.

Comment: @Jezen I would recommend as a double check, copy the text from the headers exactly and paste them into the code to ensure they are EXACTLY the same. As Scott said, an extra space or any difference will cause this to not work.

Comment: I have noticed that the only column it removes is just specifically Certications and nothing else. Mark and Scott, I'll do that. Copy the text. But my macro is correct right?

Answer (score 1):

If you have typos in your column headings, this won't fix your problem, but...

Don't rely on `Select`; pass `DeleteColumns` a `Worksheet` variable.

Also, as proposed in comments, don't rely on `On Error Resume Next`, but handle the possibility that the column isn't found:

```
Sub Dosomething()
    ...
    For Each xSh In Worksheets
        DeleteColumns ws:=xSh
    Next
End Sub

Sub DeleteColumns(ByVal ws as Worksheet)
    ...
    For Each V In Split(ColumnsToDelete, "|")
        Dim rng as Range
        Set rng = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=Trim(V), LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            rng.EntireColumn.Delete
        Else
            Debug.Print V & " was not found on " & ws.Name
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I did this while fixing the typos, however, it really will only delete column "Certifications" for some reason.

Comment: Then comment out `On Error Resume Next` and figure out what `V` is when the error occurs.

Comment: After removing the On Error Resume Next. The error in my code is "Rows(1).Find(Trim(V), , , xlWhole, , , False).EntireColumn.Delete".

Comment: So, what is `V` at this time? Analyse what goes wrong right there.

Comment: @teylyn still the same thing, it removed only the "Certifications"

Comment: @BigBen I tried your code above, and it has the same result. It only removed "Certifications"

Comment: @Jezun then you will see a list of unfound strings in the immediate pane.  remember by using `LookAt:=xlWhole` it is looking for an exact match `A` = `A` , `A`<> `A-B`